# Insert and Update with LINQ not work in DNN

Tags: c#, linq, dotnetnuke

I create a DNN(version 6.*) Module with LINQ to SQL. it was work by select operation and return true value, but in manipulate operation (update, insert, delete) when call SubmitChange() it not work:

```
    SecurityLog dal = new SecurityLog()
            {
                Date = info.Date,
                Description = info.Description,
                UserIP = info.UserIP,
                UserName = info.UserName
            };
            MyLogDataContext.CBI_SecurityLogs.InsertOnSubmit(dal);
            MyLogDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

although when i call SP binded method in DataContext it work complete.

```
MyLogDataContext.InsertSecurityLog(info.Date, info.UserName, info.Description, info.UserIP)
```

why it not work correct?

Comment: "Not work" means do you get an exception or does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a Primary Key in your table.  Linq needs a Primary Key defined to work.